# Count the frequency of words in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python
file=open("C:/python27/python operators.txt","r+")

wordcount={}

for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some text detailing what the purpose of your code is, and what you're looking for in terms of feedback?

Comment: `re.search('(\w)', file.read());`

Comment: Please do add an introductory paragraph at the top of your post. Right now your post is summarized as "..." on question list pages. You can improve that and make your question more attractive my adding an introductory paragraph at the top.

Comment: You might want to put all words into lower case before splitting, e.g., `file.read().split()` -> `file.read().lower().split()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save this syntax:

```
if word not in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] = 1
else:
    wordcount[word] += 1
```

Using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Basically a dictionary that will create a new key with a default value if you try to access a non existent one. You tell it the default value by passing a callable object, in your case `int` would just set default values as `0`.

It would simplify your code to his:

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

wordcount = defaultdict(int)

for word in file.read().split():
    wordcount[word] += 1
```

But actually, the `collections` module has an even more useful object for your purposes. A `Counter` object. It's basically a dictionary that is specialised to do exactly what you want, count instances of a key value in an iterable. You could just directly pass the list that your currently looping over and shorten your script to a few scant lines with it.

```
from collections import Counter

with open("C:/python27/python operators.txt") as f:
    wordcount = Counter(f.read().split())
```

Note I used `with` as suggested in another answer and used `f` instead of `file` as `file` is a built in object and you're shadowing it by using that name. Stick with `f` for files.

And lastly, you don't need to use `'r+'` as your file mode unless you plan to write in it. The default mode is `'r'` to just read the file, which is all you need here.

Comment: Bro you hit the right spot, cheers!

Answer (score 12):

**Use a Context Manager**

When dealing with something like a file, it's safer to write:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    ## code ##
```

That will automatically handle file closing correctly in case of exceptions and the like. I also find it clearer. Also, why `r+`?

**Prefer Generators**

`file.read()` reads the *entire* file into memory. Prefer to just go a line at a time by iterating through it.

`wordcount.items()` gives you a full list of all the items. But you don't need them all at once, you just need to iterate through them. For that there's `iteritems()`.

**Use the tools at your disposal**

You have:

```
if word not in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] = 1
else:
    wordcount[word] += 1
```

That's a lot of code for a simple operation. What are you doing here? You're counting the incidence of `word`. But there's an app for that: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
wordcount = collections.Counter()
for line in file:
    for word in line.split():
        wordcount[word] += 1
```

Furthermore, we also have [`Counter.update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update), which lets us do:

```
for line in file:
    wordcount.update(line.split())
```

Full solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import collections

wordcount = collections.Counter()
with open("C:/python27/python operators.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        wordcount.update(line.split())

for k,v in wordcount.iteritems():
    print k, v
```

Comment: I think he only wants to work with basic data structures.

Comment: `file` is a keyword in python we should avoid that. Instead we can write something like `f` as suggested by @SuperBiasedMan.

Comment: Oh, you mean since we are not changing that variable then its perfectly fine to shadow it?